# How to get the Sigma of a Rayleigh distribution in python scipy.stats

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, scipy.stats

Calling

```
rayleigh_args = stats.rayleigh.fit(num_list)
```

Returns a tuple of 2 values e.g. (-320.34, 360.77).
Where I can use it to get the CDF or PDF of the distribution for a given value.

I can't find what each of those values represents.
In addition, as far as I'm aware the rayleigh distribution requires only one scale parameter **σ** in order to calculate CDF and PDF.

My question is, what is the meaning of the scipy.stats return values, and how can I get the actual **σ** of the distribution. So I can use it in another application.

Comment: Hmm, something to look at: try `print(stats.rayleigh.__doc__)` and `print(stats.rayleigh.fit.__doc__)`.

Comment: I have read the documentation its no help, also the PDF function in the docs looks incomplete. I'm not a statistician so I might be missing something, but it doesn't  have the scaling factor on it.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rayleigh.html mentions location and scale parameters.

Comment: Typically, fit returns location and scale. Scale being sigma, or proportional to sigma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have an array of data called `num_list`, then you only need to get the average of the data array (or mu). After that, you can calculate the Sigma parameter of the Rayleigh distribution as follows:

```
Sigma= mu*math.sqrt(2/math.pi)
```